# number of downloads in playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I've had an app published on Google Play before few weeks. I can see from the developer console that it's had  590+ total downloads. Still showing 100-500 downloads on play store?

Comment: It takes some time for Google to update the numbers.

Comment: Btw this is not a programming question and not suitable for SO...

Comment: It will take time to reflect at there based on your country and in the playstore it always reflect round figure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue

Answer (score 0):

It will take some time.

Downloads are shown in following way. until number of downloads do not reaches to minimum level. The information is not updated

```
1+ (1 - 5)
5+ (6 - 10)
10+ (11 - 50)
50+ (51 - 100)
100+ (101 - 500)
500+ (501 - 1000)
1000+ (1001 - 5000)
```